# How can I define a variable name in bash that includes a variabe?

Tags: bash

I want to define the following:

```
COMMIT_ID_${ARCH}=$(git log --format="%H" -n 1)
```

But it fails:

> -bash: COMMIT_ID_amd64=a7c9e0a53972a3d42a8035f45469f1959a0475f8: command not found

Comment: How will you reference your variable later? Because while you can use your dynamic variable with declare+indirect expansion, using associative arrays is generally simpler & more readable.

Comment: Unless you will have *two* variables like `COMMIT_ID_x86` and `COMMIT_ID_arm`, there's nothing gained by defining `COMMIT_ID_x86` instead of simply `COMMIT_ID`.

Comment: I will have two.  I used echo $COMMIT_ID_${ARCH}.

Comment: I'm not actually echoing it as it is in a script and is used in a sed substitution.

Comment: All your questions about _indirection_ are answered by [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an associative array.

```
declare -A commit_id

commit_id[$ARCH]=$(git log --format="%H" -n 1)

...

echo "${commit_id[$ARCH]}"
```

Comment: It appears that the declaration does not persist across functions. Would you know how I can resolve this?

Comment: In a function, add the `-g` flag to the `declare` command to make the array a global variable.

Comment: I moved it outside the function and it worked but I think -g and keeping it within s better.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `declare` directive for this:

```
declare "COMMIT_ID_${ARCH}"=$(git log --format="%H" -n 1)
```

To examine new variable use:

```
declare -p "COMMIT_ID_${ARCH}"
```

---

Based on comments below by OP:

```
# create your variable
var="COMMIT_ID_${ARCH}"

# set variable by calling git log
declare "$var"=$(git log --format="%H" -n 1)

# examine value of $var
echo "${!var}"
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but it did not return the correct value: echo $COMMIT_ID_${ARCH} returns amd64.  I'd prefer not to have to run declare -p each time I want the actual value if possible.  I'm not actually echoing it as it is in a script and is used in a sed substitution.

Comment: Clear explanation of declare usage, thank you.  Unfortunately though it still leaves me with the problem of not having $ARCH ref in variable name as I will have amd64 & arm64v8 and need to differentiate between them.

Comment: You will have 2 different variables created `COMMIT_ID_amd64` and `COMMIT_ID_amd64v8` after above run.

Comment: Would they both not be called var?

Comment: `var` is just a temporary holder. Where and how are you going to use these 2 variables?

Comment: I am using in a bash script function so I want to define the commit_ids for amd64 & arm64v8 and substitute them using sed in another function.